# What does Windows use for dirty_background_ratio, dirty_bytes, etc?

Tags: linux, windows, hard-drive, performance

I keep running into problems with large file transfers in Linux. On one hand, transfers might be super slow. I apply a tweak, it fixes it but then my system will stutter while transferring a file. It is recommended to experiment with values such as:

```
echo $((16*1024*1024)) > /proc/sys/vm/dirty_background_bytes
echo $((48*1024*1024)) > /proc/sys/vm/dirty_bytes
echo 5 > /proc/sys/vm/dirty_background_ratio
echo 10 > /proc/sys/vm/dirty_ratio
```

Windows (Though I don't use win) never has this problem. Microsoft has clearly figured out the sweet spot. I seek to mirror the behavior of Windows in this regard. How to?

Comment: Beware that since Windows is a completely different OS, there's no guarantee that there _will be_ a 1:1 mapping for these parameters -- it is very likely that the entire logic is different as well.

Comment: maybe though you would think principals should be pretty similar and linux being linux, a way to match closely.